# jquery mobile: multiple data-filters showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to create a listview control in jquery-mobile that has the ability for certain list items to expand and show child items. My goal is that this list is filterable, and the jquery-mobile data-filter="true" attribute is sufficient.  Unfortunately, it seems to be inherited by < u l > and < o l > elements inside, and I end up with multiple filter controls.  Is there a best practice for preventing this type of inheritence in jquery?  Using jquery to remove extraneous form tags is a hack that works, but I'd rather do it as designed.

Here is a quick example:

```
<div data-role="content">
  <div class="choice_list">
    <h2>Select an item</h2><br />
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
      <li><a>Item</a></li>
      <li data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Super Item</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li><a>Sub Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please take a look at this JSFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/harlomic/SsJjS/3/.

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS to hide two of the three filter inputs:

```
/*hide all of the search filter forms*/
#test .choice_list form.ui-listview-filter {
    display : none;
}

/*show just the first search filter form*/
#test .choice_list form.ui-listview-filter:nth-child(-n+3) {
    display : block;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SsJjS/5/

Note that `test` is the ID of the page on which the list-views are found and `choice_list` is the class of the container element to your list-views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jasper, it's good to know how the hide the filters with css.  I'm still looking for the best practice on preventing the filters from being added to the DOM.

Comment: I believe you've stumbled onto a bug. I've never used nested lists like this but jQuery Mobile doesn't seem to understand the difference between nested and non-nested list-views when applying data-filters.

Answer (score 1):

I have also ran into this same problem with nested lists in JQM.

I messed around with it and if you remove data-role="listview" from your extra < ul >'s that will solve your problem, however, you will lose your JQM styling and that is not what you're looking for. We all want the slick layout and styling from JQM.

JQM should fix this as I also feel this could be a bug as I haven't found anything in the docs about this.

Comment: Thanks for the response, cshu.  This was basically the same experience I had.